# \Aboxed does not align the = in an align* with one-sided equation

Tags: align, boxes

I just want to box my last equation, but `\Aboxed` isn't aligning properly. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  e &= mc^2 \\
  \Aboxed{&= 42}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

And here's what it gives me:

[image: badly aligned equations]

As you can see, it is not properly aligned.

Comment: of topic: `mathtols` load `amsmath`, so it is enoug to load only `mathtools` ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\Aboxed` needs an expression on both side of ampersand:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
         e  & = mc^2 \\
\Aboxed{ {} & = 42}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ugh why can't latex packages ever make sense

Comment: How to write that box and the equation in blue?

Comment: for `\Aboxed` I don't know, but try if instead it it you use `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
         e  & = mc^2 \\
            & = \color{blue}\boxed{42}
\end{align*}
\end{document}` gives acceptable result.